# preventDefault works at first time, but not at the second time

Tags: jquery

I want to load next posts via ajax. the first time works well, but the second time the site loads completely new. preventDefault seems not to work.

I have seen similar question and i already use the solutions suggested but it doesn't work for me. (.on or .live method)

Here's my code:

```
        // Ajax load more posts
        var loadMorePosts = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $container = $("#primary");
            var $loadMoreButton = $("#nav-ajax .nav-more");
            var $nextPageLink = $loadMoreButton.find("a").attr("href");

            // do the ajax magic
            $.post($nextPageLink, function(data){
                var $mainWrap = $("#main-wrap", data);
                var $content = $mainWrap.find("#primary article");

                // add the loaded posts
                $container.append($content);

                // grab the next PageLink
                var $nextLoadMoreButton = $mainWrap.find("#nav-ajax .nav-more");
                $loadMoreButton.replaceWith($nextLoadMoreButton);


            }, "html");             
        } // end loadMorePosts


        // Bind Functions
        $("#nav-ajax .nav-more").on("click", loadMorePosts);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Tommy

Comment: `$loadMoreButton.replaceWith($nextLoadMoreButton);` your new button probably doesn't have the event you think it does.

Comment: use the delegation approach for `on()` .. see docs. Or bind the event handler again when you change the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the "load more button" with a new one upon each click, inferred based on this line:

```
$loadMoreButton.replaceWith($nextLoadMoreButton);
```

This causes the click event binding to be lost, as the new replaced button does not inherit the click event bound to its older counterpart. You should use `.on()`, and listen for the click event bubbling up to the `document` object instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "#nav-ajax .nav-more", loadMorePosts);
```